# Javascript default value null

Tags: javascript

How to set default value null in javascript as we make a db field null.

```
lastName.value="Null";
```

But it saves as values given

Comment: Um... `lastName.value = null;`

Comment: Is `lastName` an input field? Then use `lastName.value = ""`.

Comment: you don't have to assign null value specifically... if you declare a variable without providing value by default it will hold null in it...

Comment: @PavanKumarK Undefined variables are `undefined`, not null.

Comment: Now what type of thing is this?

Comment: You should remove the Double Quotes from the `"Null"`
and `N` should be small letter.

`lastName.value = null;`

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
lastName.value=null;
```

Answer (score 2):

`"Null"` is a string

`lastName.value= null` use this to set null value

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you totally avoid declaring it and it will take the value of `undefined` - which you can check against where required.

For example:

```
if(lastName.value == undefined) {
   // do stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var person = {
    lastname: null,
    firstname: null
};


alert(person.lastname === null);
```

Comment: be sure to check for null with the === operator as == will cast undefined to null.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Hello()
{
    var a=document.getElementById('nm').value;
    alert(a);
    document.getElementById('nm').value=null;
    alert(document.getElementById('nm').value);
}
</script>
<body>
Name : <input type="text" name="nm" id="nm" />
<input type="button" value="CLick" onclick="Hello()"/>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
lastName.value= undefined;
```

It will pass null value to server

Comment: `undefined` is not `null`, and the question never mentions passing values to the server.